# video tag play mp4 in Safari on Mac-book

Tags: video, safari, mp4

I have a mp4 file stored in different sites,
1. when the url is "http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4", safari can play it.

```
<video autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

2. when the url is "http://120.26.108.71/resources/movie.mp4", safari cannot play it.

```
<video autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="http://120.26.108.71/resources/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: how about the first video? please download the two video, and the md5 hashes are the same.